# What is the right way to deploy Java Application, Java Applet and Android Application with data files?

Tags: java, android, deployment, frameworks, applet

I'm at the beginning of Java game development and i had only experience with c++ computer game development yet. Game i'm making now is going to be for computers via downloadable version (Win/Linux) and browser - applet version (Win/Linux), also i'd like to make it available for Android phones.

I know i'll be having some trouble to handle both computer and android systems especially with OpenGL part, but i don't want to add myself more work by learning many systems for game data loading.

So i'm looking for any **library or system** how to load game stuff like levels, textures, models that is **usable with minimal differences for multiple systems - Local, Applet or Android** version.

I was thinking about plain text files and images packed into jar, but i'm not sure if it is the right way and i'd like to not start doing it bad way and then rewrite a lot of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java applications & applets

1. Deploy them using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) (works on Windows, *nix **& OS X**)
2. Put the application resources into Jars that are on the run-time class-path
3. Access the resources by `URL` obtained from `Class.getResource(String)`

Not so familiar with Android dev., but I suspect point 2. is the same 'add them to run-time class-path', probably access them using the `Context` or `AssetManager`.

Answer (score 0):

[Unity](http://unity3d.com/) i its called, its basicly platform independant.
Hope thats what you are looking for

Comment: Unity doesn't support Linux :/

Comment: I'm not looking for any engine, i'm looking for data manipulation system.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going into android dev, look at the app called AIDE. It stands for Android Integrated Devolopment Envlriment, or Android IDE. I use it, and it is extremely helpful for on-the-fly testing.

and the pics packed in a jar would be a smart idea to work with.